# How can I prevent GCE from copying ssh keys to all new instances?

Tags: google-compute-engine

When I create a new VM instance via Cloud Console, homedirs are automatically created for users that I have created manually on previous instances, and `ssh-keys` are copied to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in respective homedirs.

I don't want that! This is IMHO a serious security flaw.

I don't want any users automatically created, I don't want any ssh keys automatically copied.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: @Geet The [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6521681) you suggested on this post does not improve the post in any way. Please do not mark up random sentences with backticks, as those are for code only and having to review things like this is a waste of reviewers' time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the specific users & SSH keys to use for an instance by setting the instance level [`sshKeys` metadata key](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/instances?hl=en#sshkeys). You can also do this from the command line using gcutil's `--authorized_ssh_keys` option:

```
$ gcutil addinstance --authorized_ssh_keys=username1:/path/to/keyfile1,username2:/path/to/keyfile2,...
```

If you want to make sure that no instances get the full set of users/keys, you can remove the `sshKeys` project level metadata key. From the Console, click `Compute Engine`, then `Metadata`, then click the trash can icon next to the `sshKeys` key. You will then *need* to specify keys for each instance, or you will not be able to log in at all. (which may be what you want in a fully automated environment)

Note: Running `gcutil ssh` will generate a key-pair (if needed) and add it to the `sshKeys` key.

Answer (score 0):

Google adds these ssh keys to the project ssh-keys automatically. So you need to block project-wide SSH keys: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#block-project-keys

You can do it via meta-data:

`"block-project-ssh-keys": "true"`

Comment: this does not seem to work. Even with "block-project-ssh-keys", clicking on "ssh" will write new keys to the instance and opens an ssh window. How can you stop google accessing my VM?