# Google Cloud Compute Engine sshKeys removal

Tags: cloud, ssh-keys, google-compute-engine

This may be answered elsewhere but I seem to be unable to find any information about the removal of sshKeys after they have been loaded into the instance. My question is, if I have multiple users with access to the project and they have their keys added to the project metadata how can a single user be removed from the project, including their SSH keys and if the possibility exists will those keys have to be manually removed from each individual instance in the project and if so how without the root account?

Answer (score 2):

The Compute Engine system currently only creates accounts, so any instances that exist while those accounts exist in the project metadata will have accounts created and keys propagated. It is your responsibility as an administrator to disable this access if someone leaves your project.

Comment: Also, see this answer for some details about managing SSH keys yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21636588/92445